# How find this positive $n$ such $n<6(1-1.001^{-1000})<n+1$

Tags: calculus, limits

let $n$ is positive numbers,and such 
$$n<6(1-1.001^{-1000})<n+1$$

find the value $n$

This problem is from china compition today,(some hours ago)

my try:use this following 
$$\lim_{n\to0}(1-n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\dfrac{1}{e}$$
so
$$6(1-1.001^{-1000})\approx 6(1-\dfrac{1}{e})$$

so we have $$n=3$$

other idea
$$(1.001)^{-1000}=(1+0.001)^{-1000}=1-1000\cdot0.001+\dfrac{(-1000)(-1000-1)}{2}(0.001)^2+\cdots $$
 this idea seems very ugly

my question, Have other good nice methods? Thank you

Comment: You might want to check your statement $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\dfrac{1}{e}$ as you probably meant something slightly different such as $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}=e$

Comment: sorry, I have edit,Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Thinking of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n=e$ you are on the right track. But to be on the safe side we need estimates in both directions.

For small positive $x$ the  series $\log (1+x)=x-{x^2\over2}+{x^3\over3}-\ldots$ is alternating. It follows that
$$\log\left((1+x)^{1/x}\right)={1\over x}\log(1+x)\ \cases{<1&\cr >1-{x\over2}&\cr}\qquad(0<x<1)\ .$$
Therefore
$$(1+x)^{-1/x}\ \cases{>{1\over e} &\cr <{1\over e}e^{x/2}&\cr}\qquad(0<x<1)\ .$$
In our case $x=0.001$; so $e^{x/2}<1+x=1.001$.

Since $${6\over e}\doteq2.21$$ is far away from an integer it is now easy to finish up the problem.

Comment: Nice answer (+1) One question: that symbol $\doteq$ is it similar with $\approx$?

Comment: @Cortizol: It means "approximately equal", whereas $\approx$ means a thousand things.

Answer (score 1):

Probably equivalent to the above, but using $\log{(1+x)} = x+O(x^2)$:

$$1-(1.001)^{-1000} = 1-e^{-1000 \log{1.001}} \approx 1-e^{-1000 (0.001)} = 1-e^{-1} \approx 0.63$$

so that $6  [1-(1.001)^{-1000}] \approx 3.78$, so that $n = 3$.